# Joint Distribution of two indepedent normal random variables

Tags: probability

If you have two independent random variables

X~N(μ,σ<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup>)
Y~N(μ,σ<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup>)

and wanted to derive the distribution of  a third random variable

W = 2X+3Y+5

how would you go about this?

Comment: Do you like dollars? Use [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). And your question will be more readable, also.

Answer (score 2):

A [linear combination of two independent normal random variables is itself normal](http://www.statlect.com/normal_distribution_linear_combinations.htm). If $$X \sim N(\mu_X,\sigma_X^2)$$ and $$Y \sim N(\mu_Y,\sigma_Y^2)$$ such that $X \perp Y$, then the random variable $W = aX + bY$ is normal: $$W \sim N(a\mu_X + b\mu_Y, a^2\sigma_X^2 + b^2\sigma_Y^2)$$
You can use this information to find the distribution of $(2X + 3Y)$, and then $(2X+3Y)+5$.

Answer (score 1):

One of the very useful method, especially if you have independent random variables, is to use the characteristic function approach. If $X\perp Y,\ Z=aX+bY$, then $\Phi_{Z}(t)=E(e^{tZ})=\Phi_{X}(at)\Phi_Y(bt)$, then you can take the inverse Fourier transform of $\Phi_Z$ to get the pdf of $Z$. For your case, you can check that $W$ will be $~\mathcal{N}(5\mu+5,4\sigma_1^2+9\sigma_2^2)$

Comment: So if I am understanding correctly, I am taking the mgf of X and Y and multiplying them, and then taking the derivative of that and inserting 0 in for t? Which gives me 5μ+4σ<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup>+9σ<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup>

Comment: I said take inverse Fourier transform, not derivative.